# How to write sheet name, above the data column

Tags: c#

I want to export excel file where has like more than 4 sheets, into a pdf file

I success to export it, but what missing is each page need the sheet name above the data in each sheet, i only can export the data without the sheet name, and each sheet will create a new page ..

here's the code

```cs
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWb2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(textBox3.Text);

for (int i = 1; i <= xlWb2.Sheets.Count; i++)
{
    xlWb2.Sheets[i].Activate();
    xlWs2 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWb2.Sheets[i];
    xlWs2.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
    xlWs2.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
    xlWs2.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
    xlWs2.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;
}
            //this is how to save as PDF     
xlWb2.ExportAsFixedFormat(
    Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
    Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox3.Text) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox3.Text) + ".pdf");
```

How can I put the sheet name above the data ?
so it will be like

```
*page1*
"Sheet1 Name"

"DATA from sheet 1"


*page2*
"Sheet2 Name"

"DATA from sheet 2"
```

Comment: What about leaving an empty row at the top of each sheet and write the sheet name on it before exporting to pdf? Another solution could be using page header for each sheet.

Comment: Well, its a good suggestion I think.

Comment: @marco thats a good idea, i will try it ..